# Is this a measure of how similar two quantum circuits are?

Tags: qiskit

Suppose there are two independent quantum circuits with two qubit inputs and full measurements on the outputs. Finally we measure these two independent quantum circuits. Then perform the inner product operation on the measured results UA|inputs1> and UB|inputs2>, whether the obtained value is the similarity of the two systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are implying is that you have two different circuits. You measure these two circuits independently and collect their statistics. From this statistics, you want to determine whether the two states are the same or not, or how close they are from one another. If that is the case then that is not going to work.

Here is a counter example: Suppose you have the following two circuits

[image]

Circuit 1 outputs the state: $|\psi_1 \rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$

Circuit 2 outputs the state: $|\psi_2 \rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle - |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$

However, upon measuring both of these two circuits (in the $Z$ basis) you will obtain in both cases 50% probability of seeing the state $|00\rangle$ and 50% of seeing the state $|11\rangle$. From here you would think they are the same as state but they are not.

---

What you want to do is the [Swap-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test). Also look up the Pure-State fidelity.